# View ${\operatorname{Hom}_A(F(B),M)}$ as subset of $\operatorname{Hom}_k(F(B),M)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Given a finite dimensional $k$-algebra $A$ and two (finitely generated) left $A$-modules $M, N$ we can view $\text{Hom}_A(M,N)$ as a subset of the k-linear maps $\text{Hom}_k (M,N)$.

Now also consider a f.d. $k$-algebra $B$ and a covariant additive functor
$$ F \colon {B~\text{mod}} \to {A~\text{mod}}.$$
We can view $F(B)$ as a left $A$ - right $B$ -bimodule.
Does a similar description to the above then hold for the left $B$-module $\text{Hom}_A\left(F(B),N\right)$?

Comment: It's not clear what other set of morphisms to consider between $F(B)$ and $N$, since $N$ is just an $A$-module.

Comment: @Joshua That's true - but it's thus also a $k$-module, so the set to consider could still be $\operatorname{Hom}_k(F(B),N)$.